# Is it possible to undo last execution of a while loop?

Tags: java, while-loop

Here is an example:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 11) {
    System.out.println(i);
    list.add(i);
    i++;
}
```

Output should be:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

The arraylist should have the same values for each index but what if I don't want the 10?

Is it possible "undo" the last execution of the while loop considering the while loop cannot be modified?

I know it's simpler to just remove the last index of the arraylist but what if the execution wasn't as simple to undo (as is the case for my related problem)?

If not possible, would it be better to just modify the loop condition?
(for my problem different from this one, I'm stuck on how to modify the condition as it works perfectly except for the very last execution which modifies a whole bunch of different things that is not easy to undo as with the simple arraylist example here).

Comment: Even if you didn't know the number you can still use the size of the arraylist to remove the last element.

Comment: If the last execution of the loop calls `launchNukes()`, can you undo the last execution of the loop?

Comment: "If not possible, would it be better to just modify the loop condition?" Almost certainly.

Comment: I think you should clarify *why* you need this to avoid an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Definitely better to remove the last condition. There's no way to "undo" arbitrary code execution - it may have over-written data, send messages across a network, any number of things.

Comment: You should post your actual code instead of asking about this vague problem, where it isn't possible to "undo" code.

Comment: This sounds like you want to truncate an array. Perhaps java.nio.ByteBuffer gets you close to what you're interested in? You can specify .limit() after which you should not pass, similar to array slices like in Go.

Comment: You may just do if(something == something) continue;
Have a separate list for what not to do.
You cannot undo what has been executed on the processor its impossible.

Comment: @JQluv I have already mentioned that in my answer. Please check it out

Comment: Very well cricket__007.  I'll post a new question asking for help in modifying my while loop condition.  I still think this question should stay up to let others know that one can't undo the last condition of a while loop currently.

Comment: `Robot robot = new Robot(); robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Z);` [`System.out.println("nuclear crisis diverted");`](https://youtu.be/WqnXp6Saa8Y?t=100)

Comment: @flwy_h Very well said. Though I would suggest improving the output a bit to show what output you wanted... Also, when you refer to someone, please put an @ in front of their name like so

Comment: The "Off-by-one error" is a very common mistake in computer programming. Chances are that there's a problem at the last step that's independent of the number of steps; perhaps the previous step introduces an error that's fixed in the next step, or perhaps the last step is a special case that needs to be outside your loop; you need to analyze your program and find out what's done differently at the last execution in order to fix your program. And "undo" is a feature of applications, not programming languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll always know the last index of the array (`arrayList.size() - 1`). But simply deleting the last item in an array isn't an "undo" but rather a postoperative modification.

There's not an "undo last iteration"-type feature.

Comment: To add to this, I would say that perhaps one should try changing the while-loop condition to make one less execution, not including the last one if the execution code is not easily reversible.  From my understanding now, there is no ctrl-z type feature that just undos whatever the last execution code was in the loop.  Thanks for this.

Comment: Correct. It'd be next to impossible to undo arbitrary operations.

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways to prevent the execution of 10 with different meanings...
You will have to chnage the code in each case:

Sample 1:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 11) {
    if (i == 10) {
        continue;    //Skip this iteration
    }
    System.out.println(i);
    list.add(i);
    i++;
}
```

Sample 2:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 11) {
    if (i == 10) {
        break;    //Exit loop completely
    }
    System.out.println(i);
    list.add(i);
    i++;
}
```

Sample 3:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 11) {
    if (i != 10) {  // Only perform the below functions if i != 10
        System.out.println(i);
        list.add(i);
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Aren't you missing a few braces around the indented block following the `if`?

Comment: Definitely for Sample 3 it seems, though braces are definitely good to have in general

Comment: This is what I would do, use continue to my advantage of not executing the current loop execution. Good job.

Comment: @VaibhavBajaj: I expected something like it: Python, Ruby, etc. <g>

Comment: As I've put in another comment, the main thing I got from these answers is that I can't undo the last execution of a while loop if the execution code was super complex (i.e. no simple remove last index of array solution).

Comment: @VaibhavBajaj: AFAIK, Swift uses braces, while Python and Ruby do not.

Comment: @flwy_h Yes, the main thing is you cannot remove something that has been printed.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but it is not possible to "undo" an execution of a piece of code, no matter the language you use.

But, you can easily achieve what you want to do. If you just want to not add the last number in your array, just add an if condition. This is the best idea I have for now.

```
int i = 0;
int nb = 11
while (i < nb) {
    System.out.println(i);
    if(i < nb-1){
        list.add(i);
    }
    i++;
}
```

Here, the output should be the same, but the list doesn't contains '10'.

#### Don't remove in the list after adding

This is not a good idea to let your array be filled by all numbers, and then remove what you don't want. You make too much calculations, if you can avoid them, do it (A test code is faster than adding a number in a list).

#### Changing loop condition

As you said, you could just change the loop condition if you don't want to print the last number neither. Because in my example, you have 2 tests which are quite the same. The example is a little bit useless, maybe you want that for more complexe code.

I hope I correctly answered ! :)

Comment: I gave the upvote but my problem was not as simple as this one.  I'm going to ask my specific problem in another question.  I'll link it on the question comment above.

Comment: I supposed it yes, as I said, there is no feature that undo an iteration. You have to adapt your code within your case !

Answer (score 0):

You can define for every action how to undo it.

`list.add(i)` can be undone with `list.remove(list.size() - 1)`

Other actions, such as sending mails, are harder to undo, but you could delay the actual sending of the mail to give the user a chance to cancel it...

In some sense, this is quite similar do `ctrl-z` because neither can a word processor magically undo your actions, it has to be defined how to undo it.